# PHP - foreach loop multiple conditions?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a problem with these foreach loops if i nest them the output is not correct.. In the code below: things will be added multiple times to the database.. so i actually need a foreach loop with 2 conditions but i dont know if this is possible? I need both the product and quantity added to DB.

```
$keys = array_keys($_SESSION['meal1']);

    foreach ($_SESSION['meal1'] as $quantity)   { 

        foreach ($keys as $products) {                     

 $query1 = sprintf("INSERT INTO `maaltijdproducten`(`meal_id`, `product_id`, `quantity`, `schema_id`) VALUES ('1' ,'$products', '$quantity', '$schemaid')");
                $result1 = mysql_query($query1);
            }
        }
```

The session 'meal1' is like: product is the index and quantity is the value:

```
array (size=2)
  1 => int 1
  7 => int 6
```

Comment: you can use break; by adding one if statement in your foreach loop.

Comment: What is the expected result...?

Comment: expected result is both product_id and quantity gets added in same row to database @deceze

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to iterate two times if the array is same.

```
$keys = array_keys($_SESSION['meal1']);  //it contains the keys in an an array
```

---

```
foreach ($_SESSION['meal1'] as $quantity)   {  //it iterates the array and the value of each key is in $quantity.
```

---

I think you probably need

```
foreach ($_SESSION['meal1'] as $current_key => $quantity)   {
//$current_key -> product as you mentioned
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
$meals = $_SESSION['meal1'];    

foreach($meals as $quantity => $product) {
    $query1 = sprintf("INSERT INTO `maaltijdproducten`(`meal_id`, `product_id`, `quantity`, `schema_id`) VALUES ('1' ,'$product', '$quantity', '$schemaid')");
            $result1 = mysql_query($query1);
}
```